# How to I make my AI algorithm play 9 board tic-tac-toe?

Tags: python, algorithm, montecarlo, monte-carlo-tree-search

*In order to make it easy for others to help me*
*I have put all the codes here https://pastebin.com/WENzM41k*
*it will starts as 2 agents compete each other.*

I'm trying to implement Monte Carlo tree search to play 9-board tic-tac-toe in Python. The rules of the game is like the regular tic-tac-toe but with 9 3x3 sub-boards. The place of the last piece is placed decides which sub-board to place your piece. It's kind like ultimate tic-tac-toe but if one of the sub-board is won the game ends.

I'm trying to learn MCTS and I found some code on here:
http://mcts.ai/code/python.html

I used node class and UCT class on the website and added my 9 board tic-tac-toe game state class and some other codes. All codes are here:

```py
from math import log, sqrt
import random
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy


class BigGameState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype="int8")
        self.curr = 1
        self.playerJustMoved = 2 # At the root pretend the player just moved is player 2 - player 1 has the first move

    def Clone(self):
        """ Create a deep clone of this game state.
        """
        st = BigGameState()
        st.playerJustMoved = self.playerJustMoved
        st.curr = self.curr
        st.board = deepcopy(self.board)
        return st

    def DoMove(self, move):
        """ Update a state by carrying out the given move.
            Must update playerJustMoved.
        """
        self.playerJustMoved = 3 - self.playerJustMoved
        if move >= 1 and move <= 9 and move == int(move) and self.board[self.curr][move] == 0:
            self.board[self.curr][move] = self.playerJustMoved
            self.curr = move

    def GetMoves(self):
        """ Get all possible moves from this state.
        """
        return [i for i in range(1, 10) if self.board[self.curr][i] == 0]

    def GetResult(self, playerjm):
        """ Get the game result from the viewpoint of playerjm. 
        """
        for bo in self.board:
            for (x,y,z) in [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7)]:
                if bo[x] == [y] == bo[z]:
                    if bo[x] == playerjm:
                        return 1.0
                    else:
                        return 0.0
        if self.GetMoves() == []: return 0.5 # draw

    def drawboard(self):
        print_board_row(self.board, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
        print_board_row(self.board, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        print_board_row(self.board, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9)
        print(" ------+-------+------")
        print_board_row(self.board, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3)
        print_board_row(self.board, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6)
        print_board_row(self.board, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        print(" ------+-------+------")
        print_board_row(self.board, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3)
        print_board_row(self.board, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6)
        print_board_row(self.board, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9)
        print()


def print_board_row(board, a, b, c, i, j, k):
    # The marking script doesn't seem to like this either, so just take it out to submit
    print("", board[a][i], board[a][j], board[a][k], end = " | ")
    print(board[b][i], board[b][j], board[b][k], end = " | ")
    print(board[c][i], board[c][j], board[c][k])


class Node:
    """ A node in the game tree. Note wins is always from the viewpoint of playerJustMoved.
        Crashes if state not specified.
    """
    def __init__(self, move = None, parent = None, state = None):
        self.move = move # the move that got us to this node - "None" for the root node
        self.parentNode = parent # "None" for the root node
        self.childNodes = []
        self.wins = 0
        self.visits = 0
        self.untriedMoves = state.GetMoves() # future child nodes
        self.playerJustMoved = state.playerJustMoved # the only part of the state that the Node needs later


    def UCTSelectChild(self):
        """ Use the UCB1 formula to select a child node. Often a constant UCTK is applied so we have
            lambda c: c.wins/c.visits + UCTK * sqrt(2*log(self.visits)/c.visits to vary the amount of
            exploration versus exploitation.
        """
        s = sorted(self.childNodes, key = lambda c: c.wins/c.visits + 0.2 * sqrt(2*log(self.visits)/c.visits))[-1]
        return s

    def AddChild(self, m, s):
        """ Remove m from untriedMoves and add a new child node for this move.
            Return the added child node
        """
        n = Node(move = m, parent = self, state = s)
        self.untriedMoves.remove(m)
        self.childNodes.append(n)
        return n

    def Update(self, result):
        """ Update this node - one additional visit and result additional wins. result must be from the viewpoint of playerJustmoved.
        """
        self.visits += 1
        self.wins += result

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[M:" + str(self.move) + " W/V:" + str(self.wins) + "/" + str(self.visits) + " U:" + str(self.untriedMoves) + "]"

    def TreeToString(self, indent):
        s = self.IndentString(indent) + str(self)
        for c in self.childNodes:
             s += c.TreeToString(indent+1)
        return s

    def IndentString(self,indent):
        s = "\n"
        for i in range (1,indent+1):
            s += "| "
        return s

    def ChildrenToString(self):
        s = ""
        for c in self.childNodes:
             s += str(c) + "\n"
        return s


def UCT(rootstate, itermax, verbose = False):
    """ Conduct a UCT search for itermax iterations starting from rootstate.
        Return the best move from the rootstate.
        Assumes 2 alternating players (player 1 starts), with game results in the range [0.0, 1.0]."""

    rootnode = Node(state = rootstate)

    for i in range(itermax):
        node = rootnode
        state = rootstate.Clone()

        # Select
        while node.untriedMoves == [] and node.childNodes != []: # node is fully expanded and non-terminal
            node = node.UCTSelectChild()
            state.DoMove(node.move)

        # Expand
        if node.untriedMoves != []: # if we can expand (i.e. state/node is non-terminal)
            m = random.choice(node.untriedMoves) 
            state.DoMove(m)
            node = node.AddChild(m,state) # add child and descend tree

        # Rollout - this can often be made orders of magnitude quicker using a state.GetRandomMove() function
        while state.GetMoves() != []: # while state is non-terminal
            state.DoMove(random.choice(state.GetMoves()))

        # Backpropagate
        while node != None: # backpropagate from the expanded node and work back to the root node
            node.Update(state.GetResult(node.playerJustMoved)) # state is terminal. Update node with result from POV of node.playerJustMoved
            node = node.parentNode

    # Output some information about the tree - can be omitted
    if (verbose): print(rootnode.TreeToString(0))
    else: print(rootnode.ChildrenToString())

    return sorted(rootnode.childNodes, key = lambda c: c.visits)[-1].move # return the move that was most visited

def UCTPlayGame():
    """ Play a sample game between two UCT players where each player gets a different number 
        of UCT iterations (= simulations = tree nodes).
    """

    state = BigGameState() # uncomment to play OXO

    while (state.GetMoves() != []):
        state.drawboard()
        m = UCT(rootstate = state, itermax = 1000, verbose = False) # play with values for itermax and verbose = True
        print("Best Move: " + str(m) + "\n")
        state.DoMove(m)
    if state.GetResult(state.playerJustMoved) == 1.0:
        print("Player " + str(state.playerJustMoved) + " wins!")
    elif state.GetResult(state.playerJustMoved) == 0.0:
        print("Player " + str(3 - state.playerJustMoved) + " wins!")
    else: print("Nobody wins!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ Play a single game to the end using UCT for both players. 
    """
    UCTPlayGame()
```

Run the code it will starts as 2 agents compete each other.
However, the agent can not play the game well. The poor play is not acceptable. For example, if the ai got 2 on a row in a sub-board and it is his turn again, he does not play the winning move. Where should I start to improve and how? I tried to change the code of Node class and UCT class but nothing worked.

Update: If the board is in below state, and it's my AI(playing X) turn to play on board 8(middle sub-board of the third row). Should I write specific code that let AI do not play on 1 or 5(because then the opponent will win) or I should let the AI to decide. I tried to write code tell the AI but that way I have to loop through all the sub-board.

```
--O|---|---
-O-|---|---
---|---|---
-----------
---|-O-|---
---|-O-|---
---|---|---
-----------
---|---|---
---|---|---
---|---|---
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192495/discussion-on-question-by-vera-how-to-i-make-my-ai-algorithm-play-9-board-tic-ta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent some time to read about MCTS and more time to catch the rest of the bugs:

1. I added OXOState (tic-tac-toe), so I can debug with a familiar and simple game. It was only one problem with the original source code from http://mcts.ai/code/python.html: it will continue to play after someone won the game. So, I fixed that.
2. For debugging and fun added HumanPlayer.
3. For the evaluation of the level of games added RandomPlayer and NegamaxPlayer (negamax algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax)

NegamaxPlayer vs UCT (Monte Carlo Tree Search)

```
itermax= won lost draw total_time
       1 964   0   36       172.8
      10 923   0   77       173.4
     100 577   0  423       182.1
    1000  48   0  952       328.9
   10000   0   0 1000      1950.3
```

UTC plays quite impressive against the perfect player (minimax does a complete three search): with itermax=1000 the score and time to play are almost equal - only 48 lost games from 1000.

4. Fixed the rest (I think) problems with BigGameState. It plays very skillfully now, so I cannot win.

I added a depth limit in NegamaxPlayer to play 9 board tic-tac-toe since it could take a while to find the best move in this game.

NegamaxPlayer(depth) vs UCT (itermax)

```
depth itermax won  lost draw total_time
    4       1   9     1    0       18.4
    4      10   9     1    0       20.7
    4     100   5     5    0       36.2
    4    1000   2     8    0      188.8
    5   10000   2     8    0      318.0
    6   10000   0    10    0      996.5
```

Now UTC(itermax=100) plays the same level as NegamaxPlayer(depth 4) and wins at next level 8 to 2. I am amazed! ;-)

I won the first game I ever played at the level (itermax=100) but lost a second game at level 1000:

```
Game 1, Move 40:
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓
┃ X X . ┃*O O O ┃ O . . ┃
┃ . O O ┃ . . X ┃ . X O ┃
┃ O X X ┃ X . . ┃ . X . ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
┃ X . . ┃ . X . ┃ O . . ┃
┃ . X . ┃ O O X ┃ O X . ┃
┃ . O . ┃ O . . ┃ X . . ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
┃ X X O ┃ O . X ┃ . O X ┃
┃ X . . ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃
┃ . . O ┃ O . X ┃ . O . ┃
┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛

Player 2 wins!
won 0 lost 1 draw 0
```

Here is the complete code:

```
from math import *
import random
import time
from copy import deepcopy


class BigGameState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
        self.curr = 1
        # At the root pretend the player just moved is player 2,
        # so player 1 will have the first move
        self.playerJustMoved = 2
        self.ended = False
        # to put * in __str__
        self.last_move = None
        self.last_curr = None

    def Clone(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

    def DoMove(self, move):
        # 1 2 3
        # 4 5 6
        # 7 8 9
        winning_pairs = [[],  # 0
                         [[2, 3], [5, 9], [4, 7]],  # for 1
                         [[1, 3], [5, 8]],  # for 2
                         [[1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 9]],  # for 3
                         [[1, 7], [5, 6]],  # for 4
                         [[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 6]],  # for 5
                         [[3, 9], [4, 5]],  # for 6
                         [[1, 4], [5, 3], [8, 9]],  # for 7
                         [[7, 9], [2, 5]],  # for 8
                         [[7, 8], [1, 5], [3, 6]],  # for 9
                         ]
        if not isinstance(move, int) or 1 < move > 9 or \
                self.board[self.curr][move] != 0:
            raise ValueError
        self.playerJustMoved = 3 - self.playerJustMoved
        self.board[self.curr][move] = self.playerJustMoved
        for index1, index2 in winning_pairs[move]:
            if self.playerJustMoved == self.board[self.curr][index1] == \
                    self.board[self.curr][index2]:
                self.ended = True
        self.last_move = move
        self.last_curr = self.curr
        self.curr = move

    def GetMoves(self):
        if self.ended:
            return []
        return [i for i in range(1, 10) if self.board[self.curr][i] == 0]

    def GetResult(self, playerjm):
        # Get the game result from the viewpoint of playerjm.
        for bo in self.board:
            for x, y, z in [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9),
                            (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9),
                            (1, 5, 9), (3, 5, 7)]:
                if bo[x] == bo[y] == bo[z]:
                    if bo[x] == playerjm:
                        return 1.0
                    elif bo[x] != 0:
                        return 0.0
        if not self.GetMoves():
            return 0.5 # draw
        raise ValueError

    def _one_board_string(self, a, row):
        return ''.join([' ' + '.XO'[self.board[a][i+row]] for i in range(3)])

    def _three_board_line(self, index, row):
        return '┃' + ''.join([self._one_board_string(i + index, row) + ' ┃' for i in range(3)])

    def __repr__(self):
        # ┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓
        # ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃
        # ┃ . . . ┃ X . X ┃ . . O ┃
        # ┃ . X . ┃ . . O ┃ . . . ┃
        # ┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
        # ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃*X X X ┃
        # ┃ X . O ┃ . . . ┃ O . O ┃
        # ┃ . . O ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃
        # ┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
        # ┃ . . . ┃ . O . ┃ . O . ┃
        # ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃ . . X ┃
        # ┃ . . . ┃ . . . ┃ . . X ┃
        # ┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛
        s = '┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓\n'
        for i in [1, 4, 7]:
            for j in [1, 4, 7]:
                s += self._three_board_line(i, j) + '\n'
            if i != 7:
                s += '┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫\n'
            else:
                s += '┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛\n'
        # Hack: by rows and colums of move and current board
        # calculate place to put '*' so it is visible
        c = self.last_curr - 1
        c_c = c % 3
        c_r = c // 3
        m_c = (self.last_move - 1) % 3
        m_r = (self.last_move - 1)// 3
        p = 26 + c_r * (26 * 4) + c_c * 8 + m_r * 26 + m_c * 2 + 1
        s = s[:p] + '*' + s[p+1:]
        return s


class OXOState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.playerJustMoved = 2
        self.ended = False
        self.board = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    def Clone(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

    def DoMove(self, move):
        #  0 1 2
        #  3 4 5
        #  6 7 8
        winning_pairs = [[[1, 2], [4, 8], [3, 6]],  # for 0
                         [[0, 2], [4, 7]],  # for 1
                         [[0, 1], [4, 6], [5, 8]],  # for 2
                         [[0, 6], [4, 5]],  # for 3
                         [[0, 8], [1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5]],  # for 4
                         [[2, 8], [3, 4]],  # for 5
                         [[0, 3], [4, 2], [7, 8]],  # for 6
                         [[6, 8], [1, 4]],  # for 7
                         [[6, 7], [0, 4], [2, 5]],  # for 6
                         ]
        if not isinstance(move, int) or 0 < move > 8 or \
                self.board[move] != 0:
            raise ValueError
        self.playerJustMoved = 3 - self.playerJustMoved
        self.board[move] = self.playerJustMoved
        for index1, index2 in winning_pairs[move]:
            if self.playerJustMoved == self.board[index1] == self.board[index2]:
                self.ended = True

    def GetMoves(self):
        return [] if self.ended else [i for i in range(9) if self.board[i] == 0]

    def GetResult(self, playerjm):
        for (x, y, z) in [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7),
                          (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6)]:
            if self.board[x] == self.board[y] == self.board[z]:
                if self.board[x] == playerjm:
                    return 1.0
                elif self.board[x] != 0:
                    return 0.0
        if self.GetMoves() == []:
            return 0.5  # draw
        raise ValueError

    def __repr__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in range(9):
            s += '.XO'[self.board[i]]
            if i % 3 == 2: s += "\n"
        return s


class Node:
    """ A node in the game tree. Note wins is always from the viewpoint of playerJustMoved.
        Crashes if state not specified.
    """

    def __init__(self, move=None, parent=None, state=None):
        self.move = move  # the move that got us to this node - "None" for the root node
        self.parentNode = parent  # "None" for the root node
        self.childNodes = []
        self.wins = 0
        self.visits = 0
        self.untriedMoves = state.GetMoves()  # future child nodes
        self.playerJustMoved = state.playerJustMoved  # the only part of the state that the Node needs later

    def UCTSelectChild(self):
        """ Use the UCB1 formula to select a child node. Often a constant UCTK is applied so we have
            lambda c: c.wins/c.visits + UCTK * sqrt(2*log(self.visits)/c.visits to vary the amount of
            exploration versus exploitation.
        """
        s = sorted(self.childNodes, key=lambda c: c.wins / c.visits + sqrt(
            2 * log(self.visits) / c.visits))[-1]
        return s

    def AddChild(self, m, s):
        """ Remove m from untriedMoves and add a new child node for this move.
            Return the added child node
        """
        n = Node(move=m, parent=self, state=s)
        self.untriedMoves.remove(m)
        self.childNodes.append(n)
        return n

    def Update(self, result):
        """ Update this node - one additional visit and result additional wins. result must be from the viewpoint of playerJustmoved.
        """
        self.visits += 1
        self.wins += result

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[M:" + str(self.move) + " W/V:" + str(self.wins) + "/" + str(
            self.visits) + " U:" + str(self.untriedMoves) + "]"

    def TreeToString(self, indent):
        s = self.IndentString(indent) + str(self)
        for c in self.childNodes:
            s += c.TreeToString(indent + 1)
        return s

    def IndentString(self, indent):
        s = "\n"
        for i in range(1, indent + 1):
            s += "| "
        return s

    def ChildrenToString(self):
        s = ""
        for c in self.childNodes:
            s += str(c) + "\n"
        return s


def UCT(rootstate, itermax, verbose=False):
    """ Conduct a UCT search for itermax iterations starting from rootstate.
        Return the best move from the rootstate.
        Assumes 2 alternating players (player 1 starts), with game results in the range [0.0, 1.0]."""

    rootnode = Node(state=rootstate)

    for i in range(itermax):
        node = rootnode
        state = rootstate.Clone()

        # Select
        while node.untriedMoves == [] and node.childNodes != []:  # node is fully expanded and non-terminal
            node = node.UCTSelectChild()
            state.DoMove(node.move)

        # Expand
        if node.untriedMoves != []:  # if we can expand (i.e. state/node is non-terminal)
            m = random.choice(node.untriedMoves)
            state.DoMove(m)
            node = node.AddChild(m, state)  # add child and descend tree

        # Rollout - this can often be made orders of magnitude quicker using a state.GetRandomMove() function
        while state.GetMoves() != []:  # while state is non-terminal
            state.DoMove(random.choice(state.GetMoves()))

        # Backpropagate
        while node != None:  # backpropagate from the expanded node and work back to the root node
            node.Update(state.GetResult(
                node.playerJustMoved))  # state is terminal. Update node with result from POV of node.playerJustMoved
            node = node.parentNode

    # Output some information about the tree - can be omitted
    # if (verbose):
    #     print(rootnode.TreeToString(0))
    # else:
    #     print(rootnode.ChildrenToString())

    return sorted(rootnode.childNodes, key=lambda c: c.visits)[
        -1].move  # return the move that was most visited


def HumanPlayer(state):
    moves = state.GetMoves()
    while True:
        try:
            m = int(input("Your move " + str(moves) + " : "))
            if m in moves:
                return m
        except ValueError:
            pass


def RandomPlayer(state):
    return random.choice(state.GetMoves())


def negamax(board, color, depth):  # ##################################################
    moves = board.GetMoves()
    if not moves:
        x = board.GetResult(board.playerJustMoved)
        if x == 0.0:
            print('negamax ERROR:')
            print(board)
            print(board.playerJustMoved)
            print(board.curr, board.ended)
            print(board.GetMoves())
            raise ValueError
        if x == 0.5:
            return 0.0, None
        if color == 1 and board.playerJustMoved == 1:
            return 1.0, None
        else:
            return -1.0, None
    if depth == 0:
        return 0.0, None
    v = float("-inf")
    best_move = []
    for m in moves:
        new_board = board.Clone()
        new_board.DoMove(m)
        x, _ = negamax(new_board, -color, depth - 1)
        x = - x
        if x >= v:
            if x > v:
                best_move = []
            v = x
            best_move.append(m)
    if depth >=8:
        print(depth, v, best_move)
    return v, best_move


def NegamaxPlayer(game):
        best_moves = game.GetMoves()
        if len(best_moves) != 9:
            _, best_moves = negamax(game, 1, 4)
            print(best_moves)
        return random.choice(best_moves)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def main():
        random.seed(123456789)
        won = 0
        lost = 0
        draw = 0
        for i in range(10):
            # state = OXOState() # uncomment to play OXO
            state = BigGameState()
            move = 0
            while (state.GetMoves() != []):
                if state.playerJustMoved == 1:
                    # m = RandomPlayer(state)
                    m = UCT(rootstate=state, itermax=100, verbose=False)
                else:
                    # m = UCT(rootstate=state, itermax=100, verbose=False)
                    # m = NegamaxPlayer(state)
                    m = HumanPlayer(state)
                    # m = RandomPlayer(state)
                state.DoMove(m)
                move += 1
                print('Game ', i + 1, ', Move ', move, ':\n', state, sep='')
            if state.GetResult(1) == 1.0:
                won += 1
                print("Player 1 wins!")
            elif state.GetResult(1) == 0.0:
                lost += 1
                print("Player 2 wins!")
            else:
                draw += 1
                print("Nobody wins!")
            print('won', won, 'lost', lost, 'draw', draw)

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    total_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    print('total_time', total_time)
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry the UCT function is outside the Node class so it should be able to get accessed. I will check the stuck in while (state.GetMoves() != []) issue.

Comment: Don't worry about that stuck: not relevant anymore. It was because of wrong indent in your code posting here, but then I noticed pastebin link. I see it works fine as far I know about algorithm (nothing yet ;-) - I will read a little about it.

Comment: I see a little AI spark after the changes I just described ;-)

Comment: It is indeed smarter after your suggestions. I will try to implement your suggested improvement now. Also, may I ask what's your opinion on how to deal the situation in my post update?

Comment: I think that after a day or two since the post it is not urgent anymore. The post is viewed by a small number of people now. So, it is up to you now if want to make it clear and ask more then you can update and the post will be promoted to get more attention.

Comment: I cannot upload pictures yet. I tried my best to draw it. :)

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin: You say "It looks like player 2 has an advantage with this algorithm".  From what does this derive?  Player 1 has the tactical advantage in this game, derived from the simple principle that an extra marker on the board is *never* a detriment.  If a forced win were to exist (which it doesn't), then player 1 would have that advantage.

Comment: @Prune: fixed one more bug: it was a win for player2, when player1 won, but one of the board has three not occupied squares. All the fun had been lost for the player2 now  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, alpha-beta pruning (a-b) will improve the performance of a turn-based search.  However, MCTS has a different approach.  a-b generally depends on having a reasonably accurate board evaluation at the point of application.  MCTS pushes *one* randomly-chosen branch to its conclusion, and then propagates the result upward according to the decision weighting at each node.

If you want to apply pruning as you make your *downward* decisions, you can do that, but then rather than *adding* a-b, you're blending the two methods.  I don't know that the improvement would be worth the extra effort of writing and debugging.

---

You will get a *huge* improvement if you add domain-specific knowledge, as mentioned in the performance caveats on the MCTS site.  For each of the nine boards, consider only moves that are known optimal.  The priorities for normal tic-tac-toe are

1. Make a winning move, if available.
2. Block opponent's win, if available.
3. Take the center square.
4. Take a corner square (choose randomly).
5. Take a side square (choose randomly).

This set of heuristics will never lose a normal game.  It can serve as a starting point for yours.  Once you add code to properly identify a win, your program will speed up quite a bit.

---

Thanks to Alexander Lopatin for remembering the fatal flaw in that "never" declaration.  I am quite red-faced, as I have *taught* this very case in at least three courses:

```
- - - - - - -
```

Alexander wrote:

I couldn't put it in the comment due to formatting restrictions. Here is the one game that this strategy lost to minimax:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6    7 
--- --- --- --- X-- X-- X-X  X-X
--- --- -X- -XO -XO -XO -XO  -XO
--- -O- -O- -O- -O- -OO -OO  OOO
```

X randomly took a wrong corner square in move 4. The algorithm should play against possible fork in this move.

```
- - - - - - -
```

Prune again:

Even worse, if you know that the AI is playing with the algorithm I gave, you can *force* a win, instead of depending on random choice of corner:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5 
--- --- --- --O X-O X-O
--- --- -X- -X- -X- -X-
--- O-- O-- O-- O-- O-O  ... and 'X' cannot block both winning moves.
```

At move 4, the AI needs to see the impending fork, and side-step it with any side move (either corner loses), which will result in a draw.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe has a similar strategy but: (3) fork and (4) blocking the fork. However, a fork or blocking require to look ahead two moves, so it is now so simple to write code as with steps (1) and (2)

Comment: It is quite a different strategy for 9 boards of tic-tac-toe since almost every move a player moved to a new board.

Comment: Forking doesn't require a wholesale 2-move look-ahead; "merely" a pattern to recognize the possibility at move 3 or 4.

Comment: I disagree about the 9-board strategy.  In almost all cases, player 2 *must* respond directly to the previous move of player 1, or a win will be forced on that board.  Player 1 merely maintains this tempo on each of the 9 boards, and can usually advance her own agenda ahead of player 2's counter-attacks.  In short, the player to move checks items (1) from her own previous move, (2) from the opponent's previous move (2b) checks for a fork resulting from the previous move (and any outstanding from the last round), and only *then* looks elsewhere.  Domain-aware play greatly reduces the tree.

Comment: I agree that it can be a pattern. But "merely"? Try to explain your pattern (last example in your answer: 1,2,3,4,5 moves) to a computer. Yes, we can certainly have different views on the strategy for this unresearched game.  Could be hundreds of strategies. What about writing it down as a python function 'def evaluate((game):'  with return value from -1.0 to 1.0 and testing by the game score against another strategy? :-)

Comment: Good idea, time permitting -- which it won't, on my schedule for this month.